# Firebase hosting getting iframe related error when using hellosign

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, hellosign-api

We are getting a `frame-ancestors` related iframe error when attempting to use the hellosign-embedded library from our application, the application is hosted in Firebase

example of error message:

> Refused to frame 'https://app.hellosign.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

example of headers configuration for firebase hosting:

```
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "**/*",
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "Cache-Control",
        "value": "no-cache"
      },
      {
        "key": "Content-Security-Policy",
        "value": "frame-ancestors 'self' *://*.hellosign.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So either these settings are not being recognized, or there is a deeper issue.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the header is present and has the correct value?

Comment: Short answer, no it doesn't - I've checked the response headers on the document

Comment: Have you deployed the hosting changes?

Comment: Yes, I've created another question more pointed to viewing firebase hosting configuration, doesn't seem to be a way to do it

Comment: The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config) say there is a way... _You can check the deployed firebase.json content using the [Hosting REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/hosting/rest/v1beta1/sites.releases/list?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22sites%2F%3Cyour-site-name%3E%22%2C%22pageSize%22%3A1%7D)._

Comment: As an aside, I'd skip the wildcard for the URL scheme and just use `https://*.hellosign.com`

Comment: I have tried absolutely everything and still get same error. huge blocker for us right now.